# MVC Model Data binding list Not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My Model:

```
 public class Person
    { 
       public int name{ get; set; }
       public PersonDetail Details { get; set;}
    }
    public class PersonDetail 
    { 
       public string Passport{ get; set; }
       public List<Address> Addresses { get; set;}
    }
    public class Address{
       public string address1{ get; set; }
       public string address2 { get; set;}
    }

    var model.ListPerson = list<Person>();
```

View binding

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ListPerson.Count(); i++)
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => @Model.ListPerson[i].name)
   for(var j = 0; j < Model.ListPersion[i].Details.Addresses.Count(); j++){
      @Html.HiddenFor(m=>@Model.ListPerson[i].Details.Addresses[j].Address1)
      @Html.HiddenFor(m=>@Model.ListPerson[i].Details.Addresses[j].Address2)
   }
}
```

when page post back I can only get "Name" and "Address" posted back (Addresses property is not null). 
but for element in addresses list is not binded back. any one can help me out of there? Appreciate.

Comment: Do you mean that the values of `address1` and `address2` are `null`?

Comment: And since `Person` does not contain a property named `PersonDetail` (only one named `Details`) your code wont work. Similarly, `Address` does not contain a property named `Address1` (only one named `address1` - lower case). Are these typos?

Comment: I agree with Stephen. You mix class names with property names. Besides, in class `Address`, you use different property names such as `address(X)` whilst in your View you refer to them using `Address(X)`. Proper object hierarchy would be something like this: `ListPerson[i].Details.Passport`,  `ListPerson[i].Details.Addresses[j].address1`.

Comment: I recommend this reading regarding Default Model Binder: [The Features and Foibles of ASP.NET MVC Model Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Stephen and Celdor, please do not pay more attention on the code self, this is my example as same structure with my current project. please consider these are Pseudocode.  you can do a test in a new MVC project.

Comment: How do you think anyone can do a test on code which would not even compile! And it still wont since your property is `address1` not `Address1`. No one will answer this nonsense. You wont even explain the issue (see my first comment

Comment: Am I the only one finding funny that "name" is of type `int`?